# 100 records at a time to udf

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

I have to pass record to an UDF which calls an API but as we want to do it  parallely,we are  using spark and thats why UDF is being developed, the problem here is that that UDF needs to take only 100 records at a time not more than that, it can't handle more than 100 records parallely, so how to ensure that only 100 record pass to it in one go please note we don't want to use count() function on whole record.

I am attaching the UDF code here,it's a generic UDF which returns array of struct.moreover if we pass 100 records in batchsize variable each time then,if suppose there are 198 records then if as we dont want to use count() we will not be knowing that its last batchsize is going to be 98.so how to handle that thing.

Guys... I have a generic UDF in  which call is made for an API but before calling it creates batch of 100 firstly then only call restapi.. So the argument UDF takes are x1:string, x2:string, batchsize:integer(currently the batchsize is 100)..so in UDF until and unless the batchsize is not 100 the call will not happen.. And for each record it will return null. 
So till 99th record it will return. Null but at 100th record the call will happen
[So, now the problem part:as we are taking batchsize 100 and call will take place only at 100th record. So, in condition like if we have suppose 198 record in file then 100 record will get the output but, other 98 will only return null as they will not get processed..
So please help a way around, and UDF take one record at a time, but it keep on collecting till 100th record.. I hope this clears up

```js
public class Standardize_Address extends GenericUDF {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Standardize_Address.class);
 private int counter = 0;
 Client client = null;
 private Batch batch = new Batch();

 public Standardize_Address() {

  client = new ClientBuilder().withUrl("https://ss-staging-public.beringmedia.com/street-address").build();
 }

 // StringObjectInspector streeti;
 PrimitiveObjectInspector streeti;
 PrimitiveObjectInspector cityi;
 PrimitiveObjectInspector zipi;
 PrimitiveObjectInspector statei;
 PrimitiveObjectInspector batchsizei;

 private ArrayList ret;

 @Override
 public String getDisplayString(String[] argument) {
  return "My display string";
 }

 @Override
 public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] args) throws UDFArgumentException {
  
  System.out.println("under initialize");

  if (args[0] == null) {
   throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "NO Street is mentioned");
  }
  if (args[1] == null) {
   throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "No Zip is mentioned");
  }
  if (args[2] == null) {
   throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "No city is mentioned");
  }
  if (args[3] == null) {
   throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "No State is mentioned");
  }
  if (args[4] == null) {
   throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "No batch size is mentioned");
  }

  /// streeti =args[0];
   streeti = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)args[0];
  // this.streetvalue = (StringObjectInspector) streeti;
   cityi = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)args[1];
   zipi = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)args[2];
   statei = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)args[3];
  batchsizei = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)args[4];

  ret = new ArrayList();

  ArrayList structFieldNames = new ArrayList();
  ArrayList structFieldObjectInspectors = new ArrayList();

  structFieldNames.add("Street");
  structFieldNames.add("city");
  structFieldNames.add("zip");
  structFieldNames.add("state");

  structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
  structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
  structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
  structFieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);

  StructObjectInspector si2 = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(structFieldNames,
    structFieldObjectInspectors);

  ListObjectInspector li2;
  li2 = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardListObjectInspector(si2);
  return li2;
 }

 @Override
 public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] args) throws HiveException {

  ret.clear();
  System.out.println("under evaluate");

  // String street1 = streetvalue.getPrimitiveJavaObject(args[0].get());

  Object oin = args[4].get();
  System.out.println("under typecasting");
  int batchsize = (Integer) batchsizei.getPrimitiveJavaObject(oin);
  System.out.println("batchsize");
  Object oin1 = args[0].get();
  String street1 = (String) streeti.getPrimitiveJavaObject(oin1);
  Object oin2 = args[1].get();
  String zip1 = (String) zipi.getPrimitiveJavaObject(oin2);
  Object oin3 = args[2].get();
  String city1 = (String) cityi.getPrimitiveJavaObject(oin3);
  Object oin4 = args[3].get();
  String state1 = (String) statei.getPrimitiveJavaObject(oin4);

  logger.info("address passed, street=" + street1 + ",zip=" + zip1 + ",city=" + city1 + ",state=" + state1);
  counter++;

  try {
   System.out.println("under try");
   Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
   lookup.setStreet(street1);
   lookup.setCity(city1);
   lookup.setState(state1);
   lookup.setZipCode(zip1);
   lookup.setMaxCandidates(1);
   batch.add(lookup);
  } catch (BatchFullException ex) {
   logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  }

  /* batch.add(lookup); */
  if (counter == batchsize) {
   System.out.println("under if");
   try {
    logger.info("batch input street " + batch.get(0).getStreet());
    try {
     client.send(batch);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
     logger.warn("skipping current batch, continuing with the next batch");
     batch.clear();
     counter = 0;
     return null;
    }

    Vector<Lookup> lookups = batch.getAllLookups();

    for (int i = 0; i < batch.size(); i++) {
     // ListObjectInspector candidates;
     ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = lookups.get(i).getResult();

     if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
      logger.warn("Address " + i + " is invalid.\n");
      continue;
     }

     logger.info("Address " + i + " is valid. (There is at least one candidate)");

     for (Candidate candidate : candidates) {
      final Components components = candidate.getComponents();
      final Metadata metadata = candidate.getMetadata();

      logger.info("\nCandidate " + candidate.getCandidateIndex() + ":");
      logger.info("Delivery line 1: " + candidate.getDeliveryLine1());
      logger.info("Last line:       " + candidate.getLastLine());
      logger.info("ZIP Code:        " + components.getZipCode() + "-" + components.getPlus4Code());
      logger.info("County:          " + metadata.getCountyName());
      logger.info("Latitude:        " + metadata.getLatitude());
      logger.info("Longitude:       " + metadata.getLongitude());
     }

     Object[] e;
     e = new Object[4];

     e[0] = new Text(candidates.get(i).getComponents().getStreetName());
     e[1] = new Text(candidates.get(i).getComponents().getCityName());
     e[2] = new Text(candidates.get(i).getComponents().getZipCode());
     e[3] = new Text(candidates.get(i).getComponents().getState());

     ret.add(e);
    }
    counter = 0;
    batch.clear();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
   }
   return ret;

  } else {
   return null;
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: A single UDF accepts a single record at a time. You've got "less than 100 records" requirement for free. I must be missing something.

Comment: Hi Jacek.... I am passing the number of records to be collected then go for cleint call via variable batchsize

Comment: I don't understand _"UDF needs to take only 100 records at a time not more than that"_ That's not going to happen in Spark SQL.

Comment: @Jacek I have added more info to clear up things

Comment: What are you **really** trying to achieve. The code seems too complex (and am worried that Spark is sort of abused).